# How can I write the following query in CodeIgniter?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on an app in CodeIgniter, but I am not able to write the following query using active records,

```
select price, count(*) from fake_apps where downloads > 20000 group by price;
```

How can I write this query using CodeIgniter's active records?

Thank You.

Comment: what are you trying to do? what is the purpose of your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select("price,count(*)",FALSE);
$this->db->from("fake_apps");
$this->db->where("downdoad>","20000");
$this->db->group_by("price);
$res = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Would it hurt the query if we don't use FALSE in the select ?

Comment: Omitting, codeigniter put quotes around `count(*)`, but `count(*)` is not a field of the table

Answer (score 1):

It would be like this:

```
$this->db->select("price, count(*)",FALSE);
$this->db->where("downdoad > ","20000");
$this->db->group_by("price");
$sql = $this->db->get("fake_apps");

echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->db->last_query());
echo '</pre>';
```

> For `FALSE` in Codeigniter select:
>
> ```
> $this->db->select("price, count(*)",FALSE);
> ```
>
> *Note:*
>
> If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field
>   or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound
>   select statement.

Reference:

- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Would it hurt the query if we don't use FALSE in the select ?